# Translate this DLL include from VB.net to C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, dllimport

This has been asked a million times, but I still cannot get it to work. So I ask:
I have a DLL import (unmanaged C/C++ code) that I want to call from C# and cannot get to work. I am porting from VB.net and there the code (which works) is as follows:

```
Module Module1
    Public Declare Function autodetect_SearchAxis Lib "autodetect.dll" (ByVal onusb As Boolean, ByVal searchsubadress As Byte, ByRef portname As String, ByRef devicelocation As String) As Integer
    Public AxisCom As String
    Public AxisAdress As Byte = 1
    Public Dummy As String
    Public rc As Integer
    Sub Main()
        Dummy = Space(1024)
        AXISCom = Space(1024)
        rc = autodetect_SearchAxis(False, AxisAdress, Dummy, AxisCom)
        Debug.WriteLine("rc: " + rc.ToString())
        Debug.WriteLine("AxisCom: " + AxisCom.ToString())
    End Sub
End Module
```

I do not have my C# code-attempts at hand ATM, but I have tried various versions using the `SttingBuilder` class. I would be greatful, if somebody could help me porting this code to C#. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I now have the signature of the function of the DLL:

```
int _stdcall autodetect_SearchAxis(bool onusb, BYTE searchsubadress, char* &portname, char* &devicelocation)
```

The solution suggested by David Heffernan works partially. It is working (I don't error messages), but the returned string is garbage. Essentially it is what I already had working (with the same garbage output). I am not sure whether that has to do with character encoding or what not (I am not getting any error messages). Hope the signature helps.

Comment: Why not try a VB.NET to C# converter? =3

Comment: Do you have any sample C++ code that calls the function

Comment: @RayKoopa code converters aren't without pitfalls, unfortunately.  Being that there's a dll import involved here, I'd be sort of surprised if a code converter actually worked.

Comment: I have updated my question with the signature/declaration of the DLL and a description of the problem. Hope somebody has more suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: @packoman Could you find a solution here? It would be nice if you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should basically be:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Module1
{
    [DllImport("autodetect.dll")]
    public static extern int autodetect_SearchAxis(bool onusb, byte searchsubadress, ref string portname, ref string devicelocation);

    public static string AxisCom;

    public static byte AxisAddress = 1;

    public static string Dummy;

    public static int rc;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Dummy = new string(' ', 1024);
        AxisCom = new string(' ', 1024);
        rc = autodetect_SearchAxis(false, AxisAddress, ref Dummy, ref AxisCom);
        Debug.WriteLine("rc: " + rc.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine("AxisCom: " + AxisCom.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn! You beat me to it with a few seconds! :(

One thing though, you dont need the rc.ToString() and AxisCom.ToString(). Those are completely redundant :-)

Comment: `ref string` wont' work out. How can you expect the unmanaged function to create a .net string.

Comment: `ref string` will work (at least as well as it did in VB), see my answer to see how. -- (Also, it doesn't need to create it -- it's `ref,` not `out` -- if it's creating the string, we should mark it as `out`).

Comment: perfect answer. glad you included the `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 No, I don't think you understand how interop works. Suppose then that we assume that the caller creates the string. What then is unmanaged code going to do with a .net string?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the greatest of interface specifications. On the face of it, the caller must allocate string buffers of length 1024, and trust that the unmanaged code won't write beyond that. A better interface would be to have the caller pass the buffer, and its length, so that the unmanaged code could make sure it does not overrun the buffer.

However, assuming that you cannot change the interface, you translate it something like this:

```
[DllImport("autodetect.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int autodetect_SearchAxis(
    bool onusb, 
    byte searchsubaddress, 
    StringBuilder portname, 
    StringBuilder devicelocation
);
```

You need to declare and allocate the `StringBuilder` instances:

```
StringBuilder portname = new StringBuilder(1024);
StringBuilder devicelocation = new StringBuilder(1024);
```

And then the call looks like this:

```
int retval = autodetect_SearchAxis(onusb, searchsubaddress, portname, devicelocation);
// check retval for errors
```

And then use the `ToString()` method on the two `StringBuilder` instances to read out the returned string values.

I must admit to being a little wobbly on how `Declare` works under .net since it is a backwards compatibility crutch for old VB6 code. So I do wonder how the `bool` parameter should be marshalled. Is it a 1 byte boolean, or a 4 byte boolean? As written in this answer, it is marshalled as the default 4 byte Windows boolean, `BOOL`.

Comment: Yeah, these are a lot of the open questions I also had. So I lazily went with translating the VB.Net code dumbly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the line that's giving you trouble (per the question's title) is:

```
Public Declare Function autodetect_SearchAxis Lib "autodetect.dll" _
( _
    ByVal onusb As Boolean, _
    ByVal searchsubadress As Byte, _
    ByRef portname As String, _
    ByRef devicelocation As String _
) As Integer
```

In C#, you'll need to add a reference (at the top of your static class):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

And then you'll need to make the same DLL Import:

```
[DllImport("autodetect.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int autodetect_SearchAxis
(
    bool onusb, 
    byte searchsubadress, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)] ref string portname, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)] ref string devicelocation
);
```

The rest of the code should be pretty straight forward.

To learn more, checkout:

- [MSDN: The DllImport Attribute.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx)
- [PInvoke.NET](http://pinvoke.net/)

Comment: The `ref string` is wrong, as is the `AnsiBstr`, as is the SetLastError`.